# How do I execute a select statement in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, variables, select, stored-procedures

```
Select @sql('SELECT' + @stmt + 'FROM' + @name + 'WHERE' + @whr + '')
```

I am writing a stored procedure and I want to execute the above select statement and store the value into a variable (`@var`). Anyone know how?

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: Where's your research on this one? Writing and executing stored procedures are greatly discussed and documented. What's unclear about the tutorials and articles you should have already found?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention a DBMS, but if you are using SQL Server, `EXEC` will do what you are talking about.  Read up on it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not positive the situation but a sub query for SQL server makes this really easy:

```
 Declare @SQL
 .
 .
 Where
 @SQL = ('SELECT' + @stmt + 'FROM' + @name + 'WHERE' + @whr + '')
```

Using this syntax would populate a variable which should get what I think you're asking. So basically you just declare your variable at the beginning of the code, then you write your regular query, and in the where clause you use the above.